# How to add a set of sprites in a certain pattern

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm making a game that has a player that goes up and down if you hold the screen. This is not the important part though.

What I need is to add ENEMIES, that come toward you.

I need to know how to add the ENEMIES in a couple of different patterns.

Like this:(LOOK AT THE COINS PATTERN, HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THIS?)

[image: Coins with pattern]
[image: Coins without]

Answer (score 1):

You could define a 2-dimensional array to indicate where a coin should be e.g.

```
var coinRow = [[Int]]()

coinRow.append([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0])  // '0' means 'No coin here'
coinRow.append([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])  // '1' means 'put coin here'
coinRow.append([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0])
```

Then treat each coin 'area' as a 3x8 grid so given a starting location of the bottom-left hand corner as (0,0), do the following:

```
let coinStart = CGPoint(0,0)
coinPos = coinStart
for row in 0...2 {                       // Iterate over all rows
    for column in 0...7 {                // and all columns
        if coinRow[row][column] == 1 {   // Should there be a coin here?
            putCoin(at: coinPos)         // yes - draw one
        }
        coinPos.x += coin.width + coinHorizontalSeparation  // next coin location
        }
    coinPos.y += coin.height + coinVerticalSeparation  // Position to next row
    coinPos.x = coinStart.x                           // Reset position to start of row
}
```

You wouldn't *actually* start at (0,0), so set coinStart as required. If the groups of coins appear in a regular pattern, then you can calculate coinStart and make the code that generates a block of coins a function that you call, passing coinStart as a parameter.

Comment: can you explain the bit mask thing? or make it simpler?

Comment: @YannaiHarel - I changed the bitmask to another array for simplicity.

Comment: You @SteveIves: should use a 2-dimensional array of `Bool`, not `Int`

Comment: @appzYourLife - maybe, or an enum. I'd prefer a bitmask (although the memory savings probably don't warrant it). A bool would be less 'visibly readable' though.

Comment: ok that's more understandable! thanks! I will try it when i'm back home